# Default settings for Inkscape ?

Tags: ubuntu, inkscape

I want to take default settings for Inkcape in my Ubuntu 14.04 but I can't change by default setting.

I already remove Inkscape, and re-install, but the configurations keep the same.

How can I change by default all setting in Inkscape?

Comment: How did you remove it? Did you purge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove inkscape and all its settings do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge inkscape
```

If this dosn't work look in your home folder, show hidden files, look for `~/.config/inkscape` that folder should contain your users settings so you can transfer and/or delete those settings.

Comment: All right, but is necessary to remove using `rm -rf ~/.config/inkscape` after `sudo apt-get remove --purge inkscape -y` and re-install `sudo apt-get install inkscape -y`

Comment: supposedly the purge should remove settings as well, but when I did it I still found the inkscape folder in .config so it might be, also be careful using that command one wrong space and you will delete your entire home folder

Answer (score 0):

The Templates that Inkscape(Debian&co/Linux) use are bound to your locale-setting and are stored at: `/usr/share/inkscape/templates/` for system wide configuration.

E.g. for me, the template `default.de.svg` has to be overwritten, as root, as i need it.

Answer (score 0):

Update for readers using Inkscape 1.x.

First open preferences with `Ctrl+Shift+P`.
Now you can reset the user preferences here:

[image: reset preferences]